# Collision handling in Win32 application

Tags: winapi, win32gui

After i draw many circle i want handle collisions between a circle but i don't know how to do it  . And I want the color of the circle is random . I use function RGB() but it doesn't work . Please help me ! . Thanks .

My code

```
int wmId, wmEvent;
PAINTSTRUCT ps;
HDC hdc;
HBRUSH brush;
HBRUSH hBrush;
HPEN hPen;

static int dX[10] , dY[10] ;
static int x[10], y[10], oldX[10], oldY[10];
switch (message)
{
case WM_CREATE:
    SetTimer(hWnd, 1, 3, NULL);
    Beep(750, 300);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        dX[i] = rand() % 15 + 0;
        dY[i] = rand() % 15 + 0;
        x[i] = rand() % 15 + 0;
        y[i] = rand() % 15 + 0;
        oldX[i] = x[i];
        oldY[i] = y[i];
    }
    break;
case WM_TIMER:
    hdc = GetDC(hWnd);
    brush = (HBRUSH)SelectObject(hdc, GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH));

    RECT temp[10];
    RECT rect;
    GetClientRect(hWnd, &rect);
    brush = (HBRUSH)SelectObject(hdc, GetStockObject(RGB(rand() % 255 + 0, rand() % 255 + 0, rand() % 255 + 0)));
    for (int i = 0; i <10; i++){
        temp[i].left = oldX[i];
        temp[i].top = oldY[i];
        temp[i].right = oldX[i] + 30;
        temp[i].bottom = oldY[i] + 30;
        FillRect(hdc, &temp[i], brush); 

        Ellipse(hdc, x[i], y[i], 30 + x[i], 30 + y[i]);
        oldX[i] = x[i];
        oldY[i] = y[i];

        x[i] += dX[i];
        y[i] += dY[i];


        if (x[i] + 30 > rect.right || x[i] < 0)
        {
            dX[i] = -dX[i];
        }
        if (y[i] + 30 > rect.bottom || y[i] < 0)
        {
            dY[i] = -dY[i];
        }

    }

    SelectObject(hdc, brush);

    ReleaseDC(hWnd, hdc);

    break;
```

My picture Demo here .

http://www.upsieutoc.com/images/2014/07/14/289ccd.jpg

Comment: Iterate every circle and compare distance between it's center and the center of every other circle, if it's lower than the sum of their radiuses, then they are in collision.

Comment: `GetStockObject` takes an enumerated value (`COLOR_...`) not an `RGB` value.

Comment: @bruce965 i don't understand u can explain more .

Comment: @user1793036 so how to fix it . Please help me . I want color is random

Comment: You are trying to detect collisions by looking for pixels with different colors, but this is not necessary in your situation. Imagine you have two spheres, you know their size (radius) and their location in space. If they are overlapping the distance between the two is smaller than 2*radius, and whenever the distance between the two is smaller than 2*radius they are overlapping. Just check that in your application. You can find the formula for 2D distance on Wikipedia or anywhere else you prefer.